# XamlParseException due to DatePicker from WPFToolKit

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, wpftoolkit, xamlparseexception

Error : UnhandledException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: '/WPFToolkit;component/DataGrid/Themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml' value cannot be assigned to property 'Source' of object 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'.

```
Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.ComponentResourceKey' in markup file 'WPFToolkit;component/DataGrid/Themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'. ---> 

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.ComponentResourceKey' in markup file 'WPFToolkit;component/DataGrid/Themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml'. ---> 

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I keep getting the following exception. I am getting the exception when I run the application exe from the Release folder. I do not get the exception at all when normally debugging the application in Visual Studio. I have worked out that the exception is because of a DatePicker control I am using - as if I remove the control (build and run the release exe again) the exception goes away.

How on earth could I work out what is going wrong here?

The datepicker looks so much better but for the effort this looks like it might be to fix I may be incline to switch for a textbox which I validate when the submit button is pressed! Dissapointing...

Comment: I think it may be .Net framework version issue - I didn't mention I debug thru VS on one machine, then move the release build to another machine to test - which is where it is breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the testing machine having .Net Framework 3.5 and not 3.5 SP1. Upgrade to 3.5 SP1 fixed the problem.